# Making a char out of a string

Tags: c

I'm reading in a text file, and i know how many lines the text file is. I'm using fgets to read in a line, then strtok to break it up into chunks. I'm trying to read the first character of the line in, and take action if it's "P" or "A." I'm assuming i can treat line as a character array.  sorry if this question is super basic. I can tell form the warnings that i'm doing something wrong. Is there a better way to do something like below?

```
char line[1024];


while  (i < LINE_MAX)
    {
        fgets(line, sizeof (line), fp);

        strtok(line," ");   
        printf("%c",line[0]);   
        if (line[0] == "P")
            printf("the letter is P\n");        
        if (line[0] == "A")
            printf("the letter is A");  
}
```

thread.c: In function ‘main’:
thread.c:96:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
thread.c:96:15: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
thread.c:98:15: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
thread.c:98:15: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behavior [-Waddress]
Compilation finished successfully.

Comment: Character literals (e.g. `'P'`) should be surrounded by single, not double, quotes.

Comment: Alternatively (but less optimised), the OP could use `strncmp(line, "P", 1)`, if comparing strings is what he's after.

Comment: what do you look for when going for optimization? I'm pretty new at this, so small words are appreciated. By optimization, i'm assuming you are indicating using as little code with as little a footprint as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need single quote around a `char` in C.

```
if (line[0] == 'P'){}
```

`""` is used for strings.

Comment: So to be clear, when i acccess a string array's elements, i need to use a single quote. I'm assuming if(line == "P") would be correct if i'm comparing the entire string then?

Comment: For a `char` use single quote. To compare string use `strcmp` function.

Comment: Really appreciate the tips!

Answer (score 0):

I think It should work But only if you remove Double quotes("") as they are used for String not for Character. Instead of `line[0] == "P"` use `line[0] == 'P'`.